# get value from cookie in php class?

Tags: php

I want to pass value ($login) from cookie to $dir.
**file.php**

```
<?php
class File {
    public $filename;
    public $login;
    public $dir;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->login = $_COOKIE['login'];
        this->dir = "userFiles/" . $this->login . "/";
        $createDir="./userFiles/".$login;
        if (!is_dir($createDir)){
            mkdir($createDir,0777,true);
        }
        $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : false;
        $this->filename = isset($_POST['filename']) ? $_POST['filename'] : false;
    }
    private function save() {
        $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : '';
        file_put_contents($this->dir.$this->filename, urldecode($content));
    }
}
$file = new File();
?>
```

This is the whole code. filename and action variable are being passed by ajax from index.php page.

**index.php** This is the main page that sends data to

```
<?php
    if ( ! isset($_COOKIE['login']) ) {
        echo "Need to log in first";
        header("refresh:2;url=login.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="code" name="code">code goes here</textarea>
 <br/><button id="save">save</button>
<input type="text" id="filename" value="test.txt"><br>  
<script src="JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var url = 'file.php';
$("#save").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   },
        data : {
            filename : $("#filename").val(),
            action : 'save',
            content : encodeURIComponent($('#code').val())
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why your trying to assign `$login` twice?  just declare login like this: `public $login` Also assign dir in the constructor!

Comment: BTW: You forgot a `$` sign where you assign $dir!

Comment: @Rizier123 I added th $ sign.
it creates the userFiles folder, but it does create the $login folder inside and it doesn't save the file inside.

Comment: Also you used `$login` which i think is meant to be: `$this->login`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(You only can assign `constant values` to `class members` in the `class definition`! So you have to assign it in the `constructor` or in a `function`! Also you have to use `$this->` to access the variable of the class)

As an example:

```
class File {
    public $filename;
    public $login; //problem here
    public $dir; // $login is not getting here. It works if I remove $login.

    public function __construct() {
        $this->login = $_COOKIE['login'];
        $this->dir="userFiles/".$this->login."/";
    }
}

$obj = new File();
echo $obj->login . "<br />";
echo $obj->dir;
```

So your entire code should look something like this:

```
class File {

    public $filename;
    public $login;
    public $dir;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->login = $_COOKIE['login'];
        $this->dir = "userFiles/" . $this->login . "/";

        if (!is_dir($createDir)){
            mkdir($createDir,0777,true);
        }

    }

}
```

For further information see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: The code is still not working. I included the full code above. please try to help because I've been trying to debug this for more than hour.

Comment: @zeee9 Are you sure you set your cookie? Also i extended my example(first code box) to test it! It should work.

Comment: it didn't work. I included index.php.